# Customise wiremock response in Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, wiremock

I am using wiremock in my integration tests in Spring Boot.
I need to customize the headers in the Http response coming from WireMock server.

I configured wiremock with configuration below:

```
@Tag("IntegrationTest")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = ["server.port=0"])
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0, stubs = ["classpath:wiremockstubs/mappings"], files = ["classpath:wiremockstubs"])
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = ["test"])
@Import(EmbeddedMongoTestConfiguration::class)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class IntegrationTest
```

so the folder structure for wiremock request and responses are something like this:

```
────wiremockstubs
    ├───mappings
    │       product-not-found-response.json
    │       product-successful-response.json
    │       product-with-delayed-successful-response.json
    │       product-with-length-exceeded-pre-configured-limit-response.json
    │
    └───__files
            product-for-successful-response.json
            product-with-length-more-than-262144-bytes.json
```

In the *mappings* I can decide about the HttpStatus and in map it to proper content inside *__files* directory.

for example for simulating *not found* response it would be like this:

```
{
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/products/1002",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "status": 404,
    "fixedDelayMilliseconds": 0
  }
}
```

but for simulating some response with *OK* status, I am using this mapping:

```
{
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/products/1001",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "product-for-successful-response.json",
    "fixedDelayMilliseconds": 0
  }
}
```

Is it possible to change the headers in the response to simulate more test cases?
I want to change ***Content-Length*** for instance.